# setTimeout is unreliable on Chrome in Android when out of focus - any solutions?

Tags: javascript, android, settimeout

I have a web app that basically can be looked at as a messaging system - people can submit a message, and someone else can receive it. This all works via AJAX and the Javascript front end interacts with a PHP backend. All of this works completely fine and there's no issue.

I have also implemented the Notification system that sends the desktop or android app a push notification when a new message is received. This also works completely fine.

The notification system works using setTimeout to periodically check the PHP AJAX system. But this is where the deal breaking issues arise.

When out of focus on Android, settimeout becomes completely unreliable - sometimes it will work, sometimes it will not work at all, sometimes it is very late.

To fix this, I then moved everything into a support worker as I thought that would work independent of the browser being focused, but this is even worse - seems it is even less consistent than just running settimeout on the browser.

So is there some way to rectify this? Is there some special directive within the supportworker that I can put so that it does not sleep?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/page-lifecycle-api/) to disable/enable your timers when the page loses/gains focus.

This allows you to determine when the page loses focus (i.e. user switches tabs, hides the Chrome app (mobile) etc.

```
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() 
{
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden')
    {
        // suspend and preserve your tasks here
    }
    
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible')
    {
        // restart your repetitive tasks here
    }
});
```

This has the added benefit of reducing bandwidth when the user switches away from your tab: you can stop your refresh timers until they come back.

However, on mobile devices, if you consume enough resources doing other tasks on the device, Chrome may completely purge (discard) your page from the cache, forcing a reload the next time you open the browser or switch back to the tab.
In this case, the `document.wasDiscarded` property is set to `true` when the page is reloaded.

Check out this helpful [article](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/page-lifecycle-api/) and associated [chart](https://wd.imgix.net/image/eqprBhZUGfb8WYnumQ9ljAxRrA72/wgyY9jyBaPTlVZIrJfoD.svg) illustrating page lifecycle events.

Answer (score 0):

This API does not guarantee that timers will run exactly on schedule. Delays due to CPU load, other tasks, etc, are to be expected which may result in the actual delay may be longer than intended.

You can read more about the [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) delay and reasons it may be delayed longer here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified).

If you need immediate messaging like capabilities you should look into an architecture and protocol meant for such. Something like [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) with events would better suffice for this use-case.

Comment: WebSockets won't solve the problem of being stopped by the browser after switching away from the tab and/or switching apps on mobile devices. The browser will also stop WebSockets connections to save resources.  Use the Page Visibility API as I describe in my answer to work around this issue.